# How to see the activity/fragment related to screen in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

Have joined a new company and am new to android ui. What is the best way to see which activity in code relates to ui which am seeing in emulator or device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the app on a device and make sure the device is connected to your machine. In your terminal, run:

```
 adb shell dumpsys activity | grep -i 'resumedactivity\|focusedactivity'
```

This will output the name of the activity that is currently being displayed

Comment: Thank you, this worked but earlier one did not worked.

Comment: I will wait for other answers and check for few things myself. I will accept this answer once I finish my research about it. Thanks Saurabh.

Comment: yeah, I realized the output changed over OS versions. So changed it to cover all scenarios.